# How can I manage complicated async processing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm starting up a web application that have multiple procedure which takes some time.
To reduce loading time, I want to implement async processing like following:

```
loadXML()-----
              \
loadCanvas()---setupCanvas()
                            \
setupYoutubePlayer()---------startApplication()
```

That is, when page is loaded, I want to start `loadXML()`, `loadCanvas()` and
`setupYoutubePlayer()` simultaneously, and fire `setupCanvas()` when `loadXML()` and
`loadCanvas()` is done, and `setupApplication()` to fire after `setupCanvas()` and
`setupYoutubePlayer()` is done.

`loadXML()` and `setupCanvas()` contains AJAX processing, and `setupYoutubePlayer()` contains API access and is required API-specified callback function (`onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`).

After some days of googling, I found
[jQuery.Deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and
[Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). Speaking about Deffered, I could wrap all
processes by `Deferred.promise()` and `Deferred.resolve()`, but I found no easy solution
to implement this nested async processing using `when()` and `then()`.
And as for Async.js, I have no idea to deal with `setupYoutubePlayer()`.

I missed something? Or are there another knowledge in this case?
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super trivial and even with just jQuery promises (assuming 1.8+) you can do:

```
var xml = loadXML();
var canvas = loadCanvas();
var youtubePlayer = setupYoutubePlayer();
$.when(
    $.when(xml, canvas).then(setupCanvas),
    youtubePlayer
).then(startApplication);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make yourself a favor and use a *real* promise implementation and forget about the *roflmaolol* implementation in jQuery.

Have a look at http://www.promisejs.org/ (http://www.promisejs.org/intro/#all to be more specific), they have code examples of all sorts of usecases and a list of several different promise libs. Some of the libs is minimal barebone and others offer *extensions* to the promise spec.

If I understood your flow correct this would probably do it:

```
var a = loadXML();
var b = loadCanvas();
Promise.all([a, b]).then( function() {
    var c = setupCanvas();
    var d = setupYoutubePlayer();
    return Promise.all([c, d]);
} ).done( startApplication );
```

Or if `setupYoutubePlayer` can be called in the same step as the `loadXML` and `loadCanvas` functions:

```
var a = loadXML();
var b = loadCanvas();
var c = setupYoutubePlayer();
Promise.all([a, b]).then( function() {
    var d = setupCanvas();
    return Promise.all([c, d]);
} ).done( startApplication );
```

One could probably optimize the above code further but I leave that as en exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: Simple and best. This is what I would suggest but o already have answered it very well. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Iced CoffeeScript, which gives you await and defer keywords to handle asynchronous callbacks in a synchronous fashion.